# Map Method not called when using streams on Method reference but works as lambda

Tags: java

- I'm trying to debug a java program.
- It is not calling the method url2Json .
- I tried printing START at the begining of function url2Json.
- The START doesn't get printed.
- I tried settting breakpoint inside the function url2Json using
  eclipse but it doesn't hit the breakpoint.
- This has something to do with the streams and map.
- The .map(RestFootballStream::url2Json) in method totgoals is where it is not calling the function url2Json.

It works when i use map(s->url2Json(s)) . What is the problem with RestFootballStream::url2Json ?

To ensure everthing is allright in the functions i tried

```
    for each url in list
          String ret=  url2json(url);
          int curgoals = goalsStream(ret);
```

and everything worked fine in the above code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class RestFootballStream2 {
    static int total_pages = 1;
    static String actualteam;
    static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    static int goalsStream(String allLines) {
        int goals = 0;
        JsonObject response = new Gson().fromJson(allLines, JsonObject.class);

        // total_pages = response.get("total_pages").getAsInt();
        JsonArray arr = response.get("data").getAsJsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; (arr != null) && i < arr.size(); i++) {
            // System.out.println(arr);
            String team1name = arr.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("team1").getAsString();
            String team2name = arr.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("team2").getAsString();
            int team1goals = arr.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("team1goals").getAsInt();
            int team2goals = arr.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("team2goals").getAsInt();
            if (team1name.equals(actualteam))
                goals += team1goals;
            if (team2name.equals(actualteam))
                goals += team2goals;
        }
        return goals;
    }

    static String url2Json(String url) {
        System.out.println("START");
        StringBuilder allLines = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            try {
                InputStream is = u.openConnection().getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    allLines.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return allLines.toString();
    }

    static void getgoals(int year) {
        StringBuilder allLines = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL u = new URL(
                    String.format("https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year=%d&page=%d", year, 1));
            try {
                InputStream is = u.openConnection().getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    allLines.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonObject response = new Gson().fromJson(allLines.toString(), JsonObject.class);
        total_pages = response.get("total_pages").getAsInt();
        System.out.println("total_pages=" + total_pages);
        for (int page = 1; page <= total_pages; page++) {
            list.add(String.format("https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year=%d&page=%d", year, page));
        }

        return;
    }

    static int totgoals(int year, String team) {
        actualteam = team;
        getgoals(year);

        int t1 = 0;
        try {
            t1 = list
                    .stream()
                    .map(RestFootballStream::url2Json)
                    .mapToInt(RestFootballStream::goalsStream)
                    .sum();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("******EXCEPTION*****");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return t1;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // some time passes
        System.out.println(totgoals(2011, "Chelsea"));
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = end - start;
        System.out.println(elapsedTime / 1000.0);
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. START does get printed for me. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Your class is named `RestFootballStream2`, but the method references are `RestFootballStream::url2Json` and `RestFootballStream::goalsStream` which references methods from a different class. Are you sure you changed the correct`url2Json()` method to output "START"?

Comment: That was it.I had the wrong class name.